# How to install grunt-template automatically

Tags: gruntjs

I start learning grunt for javascript project management. Grunt requires a series of templates in order to run the tasks. All the guide or examples are saying to install the template manually by running git clone *** on ~/.grunt-init directory. I wander whether there is any automatic way to install all the required templates from current project. Just like what maven or gradle are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer but check out yeoman for scaffolding front end Web apps. It has a whole lot of cool integrations with grunt.js that will automatically run a bunch of grunt tasks on your project for you. You should definitely check it out.